# How can i know if an attachment has been downloaded from mail?

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

Recently I came to know that for mails we can,

```
 1. Track Click-Throughs
 2. Track Opens
```

Read more from this blog [You Know How I Know You Read My Email?](http://davidwalsh.name/read-email)

Now I need to know how I could know whether someone downloaded the `attachments` in the emails.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think you can. Unless you send a link to the attachement.

Comment: Aren't attachments automatically downloaded to the mail server? Do you mean "how to know if someone opened the attachment"?

Comment: If attachment is actually sent with e-mail - you can't. If you only provide link to file somewhere in the Internet - you can.

Comment: Once the file has been attached to the Email, it's basically out of your hands; the user has it. Unless you don't attach the file and give them a link to download it from your server and basically using what you have now.

Comment: Imagine that, user received the mail, but do not open it. Then turn off the internet, and open it. You have no control about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attachments are part of the email, so most clients will download it with the email (e.g. desktop clients, etc).

If you want to send a file and track whether it's been downloaded, then you'll have to host it online somewhere, and email the link. When the recipient clicks the link, the website where the file is stored can track when the link has been accessed and thus tell you the file was downloaded.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you can't.

The attachment is embedded in the email. There is no way to track what happens to it afterwards unless the attachment has something in it that will allow you to track opens (such as a reference to an external image in an attached HTML document).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Its possible to trace attachment download.

Only you can trace you'r email checked or not by the receiver.

Via sending the small image in to the email and call  you php file  path.